# Laravel with multiple custom paginations

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pagination

I made a custom Laravel pagination but dashboard isn't with the same styling , So I wanna make another one.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view

Answer (score 0):

Following the Laravel documentation :

> If you would like to designate a different file as the default pagination view, you may invoke the paginator's defaultView and defaultSimpleView methods within the boot method of your App\Providers\AppServiceProvider class:

```
public function boot()
{
    Paginator::defaultView('view-name');

    Paginator::defaultSimpleView('view-name');
}
```

If you want to use Bootstrap style :

```
Paginator::useBootstrap();
```

You have all documentation here : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view